# Proof that any set linearly independent has at most $n$ elements (when the vector space has basis with n elements)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

My teacher gave us this proof today, but I don't know if I understood it entirely:

Theorem:

Suppose $V$ a vector space (finitely generated) over the reals.

$$B = \{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}$$
where $B$ is a basis for $V$.

Suppose, also, a set $S\subset V$ L.I., then **$S$ is finite and has at most $n$ elements.**

> Proof:
>
> Let $S = \{y_1,\cdots,y_m\}$, with $m>n$. Suppose $S$ is L.I. Then:
>   $$\alpha_1y_1+\cdots+\alpha_my_m = 0\tag{1}$$ But since $S$ is greater
>   than $B$, and $B$ is a basis, $S$ can be spanned by $B$. So any
>   $y_i\in S$ can be written as a linear combination of $B$, in this way:
>   $$\\y_1 = \beta_{11}v_1+\cdots+\beta_{n1}v_n\\y_2 =
>  \beta_{12}v_1+\cdots+\beta_{n2}v_n\\\cdots\\y_m =
>  \beta_{1m}v_1+\cdots+\beta_{nm}v_n$$ Substituting the system above in
>   $(1)$, we have:
>   $$\alpha_1(\beta_{11}v_1+\cdots+\beta_{n1}v_n)+\cdots+\alpha_m(\beta_{1m}v_1+\cdots+\beta_{nm}v_n)
>  = 0\implies\\ (\beta_{11}\alpha_1+\beta_{12}\alpha_2+\cdots+\beta_{1m}\alpha_m)v_1+\cdots+(\beta_{n1}\alpha_1+\beta_{n2}\alpha_2+\cdots+\beta_{nm}\alpha_m)v_m
>  = 0$$ But since $B$ is L.I., then the linear combination above implies the coefficients are all $0$. Therefore we end up with the system:
>
> $$\begin{cases}\beta_{11}\alpha_1+\beta_{12}\alpha_2+\cdots+\beta_{1m}\alpha_m = 0\\
>  \cdots \\
>  \beta_{n1}\alpha_1+\beta_{n2}\alpha_2+\cdots+\beta_{nm}\alpha_m = 0\end{cases}$$
>   that has $n$ equations, and $m$ variables, therefore is compatible and
>   indeterminated, that implies it has infinitely many solutions. One of
>   them is not trivial, so $S$ is L.D.

I think [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces#Case_2) has a similar proof, but there, it proves directly that any basis has the same number of elements (**could you tell me why a vector $v_i$ suddenly appears in the middle of the proof**?. In this proof, the conclusion is that $S$ has at most $n$ elements.
Is my proof correct? I understood it correctly? (I didn't copy, this is my understanding of the proof).

Comment: Your understanding seems to be correct. In (1) you wanted to say that for $S$ linearly independent, $\alpha_1y_1+\cdots+\alpha_my_m = 0$ if and only if $\alpha_{i}=0$, $\forall i \in \lbrace 1, \dots, m \rbrace$. 
Then your proof essentially shows that there exists a set of $\alpha_{i}$'s that are not all zero and still satisfy (1). Hence, S is not L.I. 
Note that it is important for the argument that $\Rightarrow$ in the middle of your proof is actually an equivalence $\Leftrightarrow$.

Comment: The $v_i$ appear in the middle of the proof because they are the basis elements of $B$, and you are using them to express the elements of $S$.  Does that answer the question in bold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems nothing wrong in your understanding. Probably what makes you confused is that the proof on wikipedia is a generalization of what you learnt in your class: your dimension theorem is a version only on finite dimensional vector spaces and that on wikipedia is the full version on both finite or infinite dimensional vector spaces.

In general, in a vector space $V$, the span of a set $S \subseteq V$ is define as all **finite** linear combinations of elements in $S$. A set $S$ is linearly independent if, a **finite** linear combination of elements in $S$ is the zero vector implies the coefficients are all zero. The standard way of representing a finite combination is by $\sum_{i \in I}$ where $|I| < \infty$ as in the proof from wikipedia.